# How to alias a subfolder to the root domain in prestashop with multistore feature enabled?

Tags: dns, prestashop, alias, subdirectory

I have a prestashop located on my root domain `rootdomain.com`. Then I enable multishop feature and add a 2nd shop with url `rootdomain.com/secondshop`.

As the documentation points out, I didn't add any subdirectory to the document root directory.

The problem is, when accessing `rootdomain.com/secondshop`, **it returns 404**.

My understand is that I need to point my 2nd shop (i.e. rootdomain.com/secondshop), to the rootdomain (rootdomain.com), without alternating its url (rootdomain.com/secondshop). I thought of setting up an alias but couldn't do it on cPanel.

I'm on prestashop 1.6.1.12.

Thank you for all your help.

Thi An.

Answer (score 0):

After having stumbled upon an article, it turns out that I had a wrong URL configuration for the 2<sup>nd</sup> shop.

The expectation was to have a URL in the format `<main-domain>/<shop-name>`. For this to happen, I should have added to the **Virtual URL** instead of the *Physical URL*; according to [this article](https://www.teapotcreative.co.uk/setup-prestashop-multi-store/).

I added the fix accordingly and it worked.

Thank you anyone for having spent time reading this question.

Thi An.